# R which statement not selecting string appropriately

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to cut my matrix down to specific rows. The question is best explained through the output below:

```
Browse[2]> structure[which(structure$atom == "CA"),]

     recordName serial atom 
  1:       ATOM      2   CA 
  2:       ATOM     10   CA 
  3:       ATOM     18   CA 
  4:       ATOM     24   CA 
  5:       ATOM     31   CA 
 ---                        
572:       ATOM   4353   CA 
573:       ATOM   4358   CA 
574:       ATOM   4368   CA 
575:       ATOM   4377   CA 
576:       ATOM   4389   CA 

Browse[2]> structure[which(structure$atom == atom),]

      recordName serial atom 
   1:       ATOM      1    N 
   2:       ATOM      2   CA 
   3:       ATOM      3    C 
   4:       ATOM      4    O 
   5:       ATOM      5   CB 
  ---                        
4392:       ATOM   4394  ND1 
4393:       ATOM   4395  CD2 
4394:       ATOM   4396  CE1 
4395:       ATOM   4397  NE2 
4396:       ATOM   4398  OXT 

Browse[2]> atom
[1] "CA"
```

My question is, why is that when I type in *atom* and not *CA*, I get a different selection as to the rows. As you can see, the variable itself is equal to "CA".

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The piles of other variables really aren't necessary for the example - I've removed them. Is your data a `data.table` or a `data.frame` by the way?

Comment: It's important to note that you're not using a data.frame, you're using a data.table. A data.table evaluaties it's indexes in the context of the data.table itself. This means you can do `structure[atom=="CA"]` and it also means that if you have a variable named `atom`, then it's the same as `structure[atom==atom]` which returns all rows because it finds the "atom" symbol in the table first and uses that value.

Comment: I think it's a `data.table` and the `atom` after the `==` is evaluated in the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`data.table` evaluates names in the environment of the table first, that is, columns.

Example:

```
> x <- data.table(a=1:5, b=11:15)
> x[a==1]
   a  b
1: 1 11
> a <- 1
> x[x$a==a]
   a  b
1: 1 11
2: 2 12
3: 3 13
4: 4 14
5: 5 15
```

As MrFlick indicates, the last statement is equivalent to `x[a==a]`.  Both `a`'s are the column in `x`.

Note that `which` is not necessary nor helpful for this operation, and for `data.table`, the trailing `,` is not required to select rows.

Answer (score 1):

@matthewlundberg gave you the proper explanation, as for the workaround, use `get()`:

```
 structure[which(structure$atom == get("atom", envir=globalenv())),]
```

On a side note, there is a lot of superfluous syntax in your statement. Namely, `which` is not needed, and there is no need to reference the datatable itself within the `i=` argument, and no need for the ending comma

ie,  use

```
 structure[atom == get("atom", envir=globalenv())) ]
```